# WCF service File not found exception

Tags: c#, wcf, interop

I'm using a WCF service to generate documents using Office Interop. i have several document templates in the WCF project in a folder called Templates. in the generation method i'm calling

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc;
doc = word.Documents.Add(TemplatePath);
```

that call (above) returns an exception file not found. this is how i get the path for the document

```
TemplatePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location).ToString() + "\\Templates\\TemplateAX1B.docx";
```

anyone can tell me what i'm doing wrong here and how i can access those templates ?

Comment: file not found exception is caused by GetDirectoryName?

Comment: by the word.Documents.Add(TemplatePath);

Comment: `Documents.Add` Returns a Document object that represents a new, empty document added to the collection of open documents.

Comment: yeah i got the same code working in a Windows app now i need to make it work in the webservice side i'm not sure where those files are stored or how to access them it's not a problem with the code

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps. I haven't tested it.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application WordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc;
doc = WordApp.Documents.Add(TemplatePath);
```

Try to check if the file exists using `System.IO.File.Exists`. You might not have the proper the extension.

Comment: yup that's how the code looks like i can't share the whole code as it's scattered around but the problem i have is not with the code it's with the path

Comment: Can you try to check if the system exists using `System.IO.File.Exists`?

Comment: `System.IO.File.Exists` returns false

Comment: That means the file doesn't exist. Check the path then. Either the extension is not correct or the referenced assembly is located somewhere else.